# GAE app.yaml appears to be inconsistently routing requests

Tags: google-app-engine, handler, wsgi

I have the following in app.yaml:

```
- url: /gae_mini_profiler/static
  static_dir: gae_mini_profiler/static

- url: /gae_mini_profiler/.*
  script: gae_mini_profiler/main.py

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

and the following in gae_mini_profiler/main.py:

```
def main():
    logging.critical("gae_mini_profiler request!")
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

However, when I fire requests to, say, /gae_mini_profiler/request?request=ABC, and repeatedly reload the page, sometimes I will get the proper response (as well as a "gae_mini_profiler request!" log entry, and sometimes I get a blank response and nothing in the App Engine logs other than a 200 with an empty response body.

This is completely reproducible, only happens in the live environment, and I'd say ~50% of the refreshes work while 50% do not.

This only happens in production. Any ideas?

Comment: Are those "blank" requests showing up in the logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have this stanza at the end of your `main.py`?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The first time a given appserver handles a request with a given handler, it simply imports it. This stanza tells the interpreter to run the `main()` function when imported as a handler. On subsequent requests, the appserver runs main directly, which is why you're seeing output every other time.

Comment: That was it, silly mistake, thanks Nick! https://github.com/kamens/gae_mini_profiler/commit/df6614e6195b76db24b103d03972f4ce020b6dea